# Increasing value in database after interval of time

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i am working on a codeigniter project in which i am making a counter of every movie that is being clicked. Now i want if the user clicks the movie link the user is directed to the movie page and after 30 seconds the counter will be increased to 1. Currently the counter is increased on every click. Any Help???

Here is my view code

```
<a href="<?php $id= $result[$i]->id; echo site_url("site/watch_movie?id=$id");?>" class="watch_but1" target="_blank">Watch in HD</a>
```

Here is my controller code

```
public function watch_movie()
{
    //$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    $this->movie_counter->add_counter($id);

    //$data['comment'] = $this->site_upload->fetch_comments($id);
    //redirect ('site/play_movie', $result);
    $this->load->view('Play_movie', $result);
}
```

Comment: You can store the IP that clicks the link, then check if the IP is unique,if it is unique that is a valid count if a user refreshes it wont add a count since you are checking for unique IP's. That's a start.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Queue!
Every click you insert into the queue, and another job (cronjob) insert every minute (smallest interval) the data from the queue in the correct table.

Answer (score 0):

counter will be increased even every refresh too in this scenario, whateva you are saying for 30 sec interval ( you can use ajax request with a 30 sec timeout) but this seems like a buggy code what if some one closes it before 30 sec (browser) and you don't get any increment....

if you want to setup unique (views) use browser/ip/time based (for generic setup you can make it advance) and every time you get the request of counter addition check your db if you have same ip/browser and less duration as you say(30 sec or 1 min) then don't add other wise add 1 to script.